# javascript: присваивание переменным в фигурных скобках

Tags: javascript, reactjs, переменные

Читаю статью https://habr.com/ru/company/tinkoff/blog/503136/

И вижу такой код:

```
class AnyComponent extends Component {
   onClick = () => {
    const { model } = this.props;
       model.doSomething();
   };

  render() {
       return (
           <Button onClick={this.onClick} />
       );
   }
}
```

Поясните пожалуйста, что это за странная запись:

```
const { model } = this.props;
```

Что это значит? Это больше к React, а не javascript?

Comment: это js. https://learn.javascript.ru/destructuring#destrukturizatsiya-obekta

Comment: Деструктуризация. Основы

Comment: @Elmir, да, я что-то сразу не сообразил, что они тем самым получают `this.props.model`. Тут вопрос - а зачем это делается, а не используется напрямую `this.props.doSomething();`

Comment: @Zhihar Ну такое забывается если не часто пользоваться. Предполагаю что внутри this.props есть model, создается новая переменная с таким же названием, и уже на нём применяется метод. Согласитесь так удобней и гибче.

Answer (score 2):

Это деструктуризация объекта в JS,в реакте тоже используют

Comment: Да, до меня что-то сразу не дошло, что `model` - это член `this.props`. Тут возникает второй вопрос - зачем вообще было создавать переменную `model`, когда можно было бы сразу использовать `this.props.doSomething();`. Зачем было лишнее телодвижение?

Comment: @Zhihar разработчик просто хочет короткие переменные.

Comment: @Zhihar, только `this.props.model.doSomething()`. Выделять отдельную переменную удобно если с ней нужно сделать несколько действий. Или выделить несколько переменных, что бы не писать сто раз `this.props.` Конкретно в этом коде это конечно не так заметно и в общем-то можно было и не выделять.